# How to format eclipse so that '.' operator is indented on the same line

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, indentation

Eclipse's Indentation

```
gpcMappingResponseObjects
                .set(obj.getId(), new GpcMappingResponseObject(tags));
```

What I want is

```
gpcMappingResponseObjects.
    set(obj.getId(), new GpcMappingResponseObject(tags));
```

How do I format eclipse to achieve this?
I don't see any preferences for '.'
I want to achieve this by pressing ctrl+shift+f